# sprintf broken in RubyMotion

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

Ruby noob, just got and installed RubyMotion, created my first program and I'm having trouble getting the Time (sample) app to work.

Whenever I try to format a string using either sprint or the other form (sorry don't know the name) I just get my format string back.

i.e. (from the console while my app is running in Simulator)

```
Build ./build/iPhoneSimulator-5.1-Development
Simulate ./build/iPhoneSimulator-5.1-Development/Timer.app
(main)>> @time = 0.1
=> 0.0999999940395355
(main)>> string = sprintf("%.1f", @time)
=> "%.1f"
(main)>> string
=> "%.1f"
(main)>> "%.1f" % @time 
=> "%.1f"
(main)>>
```

The same result in the actual app in the Simulator.

I do have the default ruby installed on my Mac but if I try running a test ruby file (print "%05d" % 123) I get expected results.

```
/usr/bin/ruby -v 
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]
/Library/RubyMotion/bin/ruby -v
MacRuby 0.12 (ruby 1.9.2) [universal-darwin11.0, i386]
```

Running on Lion 10.7.3, any advice or ideas appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be a bug with RubyMotion; and the `NSString.stringWithFormat` method is not functioning properly either (`NSString.stringWithFormat("%0.1f", 0.1)` returns `"0.0"`). I'm filing a support ticket.

Comment: Also, I think this was a regression with RubyMotion 1.1 or 1.2; when I ran the Locations sample app on 1.0, it displayed the coordinates just fine, but running it now just prints "%0.3f, %0.3f" on the screen. There's also an [issue opened on Github](https://github.com/HipByte/RubyMotionSamples/issues/4) for this

Comment: It's fixed. `sudo motion update` to get the update.

Answer (score 1):

**As of 5/9/12, this has been fixed. Make sure you're on RubyMotion 1.3 (run `sudo motion update`) and string formatting will work again.**

Update 5/8/12: [Confirmed bug](https://github.com/HipByte/RubyMotionSamples/issues/4#issuecomment-5579428), should be fixed this evening or tomorrow.

Per my comments above, there is definitely a bug with this. An ugly hack to get this working could be something like this (since `%d` still works fine for `sprintf`):

```
@time = 0.1
sprintf("%d", (@time * 10).round).insert(-2, '.')
```

Comment: I ran "sudo motion update" this AM, it updated RubyMotion to 1.3, ran my test again, things appear to be working fine.